# How to sent Json over web socket connection in Mattermost?

Tags: ios, objective-c, websocket, mattermost

I am working on Mattermost API.
Currently i am stuck with web socket.
To authenticate with an authentication challenge, first connect the WebSocket and then send the following JSON over the connection

{
  "seq": 1,
  "action": "authentication_challenge",
  "data": {
    "token": "mattermosttokengoeshere"
  }
}
How can i sent this JSON.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Mattermost 3.5 and later, you can authenticate your WebSocket by connecting and then providing the token in a JSON formatted authentication challenge over the WebSocket.

An example authentication challenge would look like this:

{
    "seq": 1,
    "action": "authentication_challenge",
    "data": {
        "token": "mattermosttokengoeshere"
    }
}
If the WebSocket authenticates correctly then you will receive a standard ok response looking like this:

{
    "status": "OK",
    "seq_reply": 1
}

All previous versions of Mattermost before 3.5 will require the token in the cookie. Mattermost 3.5 still supports authenticating through the cookie.

See this forum post for further information: https://forum.mattermost.org/t/how-to-pass-credentials-to-websocket-from-external-domain/2500/2